# How to arrange search results by the date they were created on?

Tags: python, django

I made a search bar but it gives the queries in an old to new order i want to change that to a new to old. I want to see the recent matches for my search first then the more old ones.

views.py

```
    search_term=''
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        search_term_extract = request.GET['search']
        search_term = Blog.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_term_extract)|Q(author__username__icontains=search_term_extract))
        paginator = Paginator(search_term, 8)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        paginator_page = paginator.get_page(page)
        results=search_term.all()['-date_posted']
        message=True
        nav=False
```

and models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: use order_by("-date_posted"). for more refe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .order_by() on your queryset:

```
search_term = Blog.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_term_extract)|
                             Q(author__username__icontains=search_term_extract)).order_by("-date_posted")
```